# Getting a response from Cfajaximport / ajax with coldfusion

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, response

I've searched a number of the previous responses, but none of them have helped me.  I'm actually extrapolating on another script I found earlier.... but I'm not sure how to capture the response in AJAX.  I was guessing that handleResponse would just capture whatever is outputted on checkdomain.cfm, but I can't seem to make that happen so I can output it.  So in the example below, somehow the person who developed this script was able to get back AVAILABLE from checkdomain.cfm, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Thanks in advance!

```
<head>
...
<cfajaximport />
...
    <script>
        function handleResponse(s) {
            if(s == "AVAILABLE") {
                //rewrite span
                var domainspan = document.getElementById('DomainStatus');
                var newcontent = "Available To Register :)";
                domainspan.innerHTML = newcontent;
                var loadingspan = document.getElementById('frmGO');
                var newcontent = "<input name='' value='GO!' class='search_domain_go' type='submit' />";
                loadingspan.innerHTML = newcontent;
            } else {
                //rewrite span
                var domainspan = document.getElementById('DomainStatus');
                var newcontent = "Unavailable To Register :(";
                domainspan.innerHTML = newcontent;
                var loadingspan = document.getElementById('frmGO');
                var newcontent = "<input name='' value='GO!' class='search_domain_go' type='submit' />";
                loadingspan.innerHTML = newcontent;
            }
        }

        function CheckDomain() {
            var loadingspan = document.getElementById('frmGO');
            var newcontent = "<input name='' type='image' class='search_domain_go' src='images/ajax-loader.gif' alt='' />";
            loadingspan.innerHTML = newcontent;
            ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm('frmDomainCheck','checkdomain.cfm',handleResponse);
        }
    </script>
...
</head>

<body>
...
        <div class="search_domain">
            <div class="search_domain_form">
            Search Your Domain Here<br />
                <form method="post" action="" onSubmit="CheckDomain();return false;" id="frmDomainCheck">
                    <input class="search_domain" name="frmURL" id="frmURL" value="Please enter your domain name here..." onfocus="if(this.value == 'Please enter your domain name here...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Please enter your domain name here...';}" type="text" />
                    <span id="frmGO"><input name="" value="GO!" class="search_domain_go" type="submit" /></span>
                <form>
            </div><!-- /# end search form -->
            <div class="domain_features">
                <ul>
                    <li><span id="DomainStatus">Type in the domain and click 'GO' to check its availability.</span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
...
</body>
```

Comment: check doc of `ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm` and your browser's dev tool to debug the ajax request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your code and then added the following for checkdomain.cfm

```
<cfoutput>AVAILABLE</cfoutput>
```

It worked just fine. In your handleResponse function, put an `alert(s);` statement at the top to see just what you're getting back from checkdomain.

Comment: Thanks Jason...just for anyone else's reference...here's the two things I learned to get it to return.  1) I had to use cfoutput as you did above, which I didnt guess since I wasn't placing a variable inside. 2) it only worked after I used form method GET rather than POST.  I would figure it would return the data the same way regardless...but POST for me does not return any value, GET does.